# Algebra : higher value of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a$ is a whole number, greater than $0$. We have: 
$$2x+a=y \\
a+y=x \\
x+y=z$$
What is the largest value of the the expression $x + y + z$?

Comment: It's $-10$; did I win something?

Comment: How did you find the answer?? you'll win my gratitude haha

Answer (score 2):

Solve your linear system for $x,y,z$ in terms of $a$. You'll find $x+y+z=-10a$

> From the third equation you see that you only need to find $2x+2y$. From the first equation you have $y=2x+a$ and, substituting in the third equation you get $2a+2x=x$, so $x=-2a$ and $y=-3a$. Thus $x+y+z=2x+2y=-10a$.